# How can I receive multiple messages from one connection?

Tags: python, sockets

I have a server and I need it to receive multiple connections and messages.
The server receives new connections without problems but it doesn't get multiple messages from one connection.

```
import socket
import select


HEADER_LENGTH = 1024

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)


try:
    server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as e:
    print(str(e))

print("Server is connected")

server_socket.listen(5)

sockets_list = [server_socket]
clients = {}
print("Server is listening")


def receive_message(conn):
    try:
        data = conn.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)

        if not len(data):
            return False

        strdata = data.decode('utf-8')

        print(strdata)
        return strdata

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return False


def handle_client():
    conn, addr = server_socket.accept()

    print(f"Accepted new connection from {addr[0]}:{addr[1]}")

    sockets_list.append(conn)


while True:
    read_sockets, _, exception_sockets = select.select(sockets_list, [], [], 0)

    for i in read_sockets:

        if i == server_socket:

            handle_client()


        else:

            print("received message")

            message = receive_message(i)

            if message is False:


                sockets_list.remove(i)

                try:
                    del clients[i]
                except KeyError:
                    pass

                continue


            if message is not None:
                    clients[i] = message





            if message is not None:
                for client_socket in clients:
                    if client_socket != i:
                        client_socket.send(str.encode(message))
                        print("sent to all players")
```

What happens it that after receiving the first message, the server stops receiving messages from that connection.
And of course there is a lot more code but I showed you the relevant code.

I'll be very happy if someone helps me with that, I've surfed the web so much but haven't seen a solution for my problem.

updates:
I've  tried to put `socket.close()` on my client side(written in Java) and then server gets maximum 2 messages and the problems with it are:
1. The server gets maximum 2 messages.
2. the connection changes(I need that the connection will stay static if possible)

Comment: I saw the examples but they don't answer my need.
I want to add the clients to a dictionary and will be always connected to get notifications and etc..

Comment: What does ```server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)``` . I know that is not about your question but i dont know that.

Comment: From what I've understood, The `socket.SO_REUSEADDR` allows the code to reuse the address multiple times. 
And if the address disconnected short time ago, the socket will not be "angry"

Comment: About the second example, this example doesn't answer my problem either.
Because, where does he save the connections?
Again, I want to save the clients in a dictionary (look my code) and then loop the dictionary and send them messages and also, they are always connected.

Answer (score 0):

try this code block

```
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import socket
import sys

#get machine ip address
server_ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
#create socket object
s = socket.socket()

#define port number
port = 6666

#bind ip and port to server
s.bind((server_ip,port))

#now waiting for clinet to connect
s.listen(5)
print("Enter this ip to connect your clinet")
print(server_ip)

clients = []
flag = True
recv_data = ""
if not clients:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print("this is c ",c," this is  Addr ",addr)
    clients.append(c)
    recv_data = c.recv(1024)

    print(recv_data.decode("utf-8"))

if flag == True:

    while recv_data.decode("utf-8") != "EX":    
        recv_data = c.recv(1024)
        recv_data.decode("utf-8")

        if recv_data.decode("utf-8") == "EX":
            s.close()
            print("check false")
            break
s.close()
```